# Total of several values in field for points within polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, point-in-polygon

I have ~4000 insurance claims for a city. I have made a fishnet and would like to count the number of claims within each polygon. It is easy to count the total number of claims, but I would like to find out how many claims there are within each cell for every claim date.

This is how the data set looks like:

```
    FID Shape       Name    Date    
83  Point ZM    A2528   20030718
84  Point ZM    A2529   20100814
85  Point ZM    A2530   20140831
86  Point ZM    A2531   20140831
87  Point ZM    A2532   20140831
88  Point ZM    A2533   20110607
89  Point ZM    A2534   20120116
90  Point ZM    A2535   20100915
91  Point ZM    A2536   20100813
92  Point ZM    A2537   20140831
```

As you can see, the flood claims are from different dates (~50). Does anyone of you have an idea how to solve this problem? I have read some similar Q&A's ([Compute total area of several polygons within a polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166972/compute-total-area-of-several-polygons-within-a-polygon); [Total of attribute field of point layer per polygon layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53678/total-of-attribute-field-of-point-layer-per-polygon-layer); [How to write FIDs of points within each polygon to polygon field?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/how-to-write-fids-of-points-within-each-polygon-to-polygon-field)), but could not find any answer that works in this case. The resulting table will consist of ~4000 rows (one for each cell) and ~50 columns (one for each claim date). The value in each field will tell how many flood claims there are in each cell for a certain date.

I work in ArcMap 10.1.

[image: How the data looks like in ArcMap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersect the Points with the Polygons. Each Point will then have the ID of the Polygon. From there, use the [Summary Statistics tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000), using the Polygon ID and the Date columns in the "Case Fields" parameter. Specify "COUNT" as the statistic desired in your output table.

Comment: Thank you for the idea with Intersect! That works fine. But how do you mean with Summary Statistics? I did only manage to get the total number of claims for each Polygon ID (result is a table with 4000x1). I need to know how many there are for each date (4000x50).
Anyway, the Intersect function helps me to continue the work with Pivot table in Excel, which gives me the 4000x50 table. I will import the data back into ArcMap after the Pivot analysis.

Comment: @JSörensen - I revised the answer to include a link to the Summary Statistics tool documentation. Your PivotTable solution works as well; the upside to using the Intersect-then-Statistics method is that you can link the tools in ModelBuilder to perform these tasks on a scheduled basis, as your incident points change over time.

Answer (score -1):

You can manipulate the Field Map of Spatial Join tool to achieve the same.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, and maybe give an example?